Home a servo motor after power shutdown
Background: I'm trying to setup a servo motor 1171MG with a 555 timer and finetune the position with a potentiometer as it depends on various project aspects.
The circuit is driven by a small board "Trigger Switch Drive Module PWM Regulator Control" which is in turn activated by an external signal and when the signal goes off, I want to home back the motor.
I already tested this on breadboard and it's working fine, attempting to home the motor "mechanically" by using different springs. Unfortunately, due to the motor position and limited space in final project, I can't get it working correctly: it sometimes works, while it sometimes it can't get the lever back as I need. I tried various different springs unsuccesfully.
So, I was thinking to add a second 555 timer circuit to home the motor, designing it in its own static configuration to send the motor to 0 position.
Now, what I wish achieve is: when the source signal goes off, the first cirucit shuts down while the second should get powered for short period of time (i.e. 2-3 seconds), enough to home the servo and power down until the source signal will get back.
I attempted to do so by simulating i.e. a discharging capacitor but I really can't find a way to get it working due to my lack of experience on this field...
Here is the circuit with single 555 that I could simulate with circuitjs and build.

On the right side, the switch board for which I found and reported the circuit; on the left side the 555 driving the motor. Note: circuitjs hasn't a component for servo motors, so there I used a DC Motor.
Please be kind with me, is the first project I attempt without the help of boards like arduino :-)
Anyways, I would avoid it because the final project will be very limited in space, I will just have the room for a small PCB with its own specific shape which I'm going to design afterwards.

You can include a second 555 timer that will activate when the source signal goes off and run for a specified period (2-3 seconds) to home the servo motor.

Hi, this is what I was thinking to do, but it means the 555s must be kept always powered while what I was trying to do is to shut it/them when done....
